# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driv5r

Tags: grails, jdbc, classnotfoundexception, urlloader, ggts

I am trying to run a grails application and after doing run-app.

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.1

| Configuring classpath

Resolving [test] dependencies...

Resolving [runtime] dependencies...

| Configuring classpath.

| Environment set to development.....

| Packaging Grails application.....

| Compiling 54 source files

| Compiling 54 source files..

| Compiling 43 source files

warning: Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing.
Use -proc:none to disable annotation processing or -implicit to specify a policy for implicit compilation.
1 warning
| Compiling 43 source files.....
| Running Grails application



Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driv5r'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driv5r
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
.
.
.
.


  at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

**Why does it spells 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driv5r' and not 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'**

Tried grails clean Refresh Dependencies but still same error is there any external way to add this driver class , i am working on GGTS.

Comment: The manual way is to put the msyql-connect-XXX.jar into your lib folder and uninstall mysql plugin -

Comment: Please include the code that triggers this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you were being careless.`com.mysql.jdbc.Driv5r` really.The main and obvious reason for this is the spelling mistake in driverClassName definition in datasource.groovy.

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driv5r"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    url = dataSourceProperties.getProperty("datasource.url")
    username = dataSourceProperties.getProperty("datasource.username")
    password = dataSourceProperties.getProperty("datasource.password")
}
```

correct the **driverClassName** from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driv5r` to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Other than this also make sure whether you have added dependency for mysql in BuildConfig.groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code where you are doing this.

```
Class.forName(driver);// here Check variable "driver"
 String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; // here you might have typed "com.mysql.jdbc.Driv5r"
```

OR

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//here you might have typed com.mysql.jdbc.Driv5r
```

> All other looks fine.. So this may be the reason.